# Using useSelector value in function property

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a React application that relies on the value produced by a `useSelector` listener within a function that I pass as a property to a child component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "./Button"
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {getButtonValue} from "../redux/store"
 
export const Parent = () => {
    const buttonValue = useSelector(getButtonValue);

    const onSubmit = () => console.log(`here with value '${buttonValue}'`);

    return <Button onSubmit={onSubmit} />
}
```

and the child button:

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import {setButtonValue} from "../redux/store";

type Props = {
    onSubmit: () => void;
};

export const Button = ({onSubmit}: Props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const onButtonClick = () => {
        dispatch(setButtonValue("inside button"));
        onSubmit();
    }

    return <div onClick={onButtonClick}>Click me!</div>
}
```

When a user clicks this button, the console that outputs reads `here with value 'initial value'` Whereas I'd expect the selector to have value `inside button`, as it was just set to that on the button click.

I'm learning that the reason this value does not seem to be updated is because `dispatch()` is an async operation and therefore the console is likely happening before the selector is updated and the `onSubmit` definition is re-rendered. Suggestions have been to pass the `buttonValue` directly to the function prop on button click. That works in this specific example, but it is much more complex when the `Parent` and `Button` components are separated by 8-10 other components in our real application (leads to a lot of prop drilling). Is that still the suggested solution, or is there a better way of handling this?

Looking for suggestions on best practices here.

[An example of this in playground](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-typescript-useselector-delay-68fxcd?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FButton.tsx%3A20%2C2&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clplmmv4200063b6lmki6ftgp%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clplmmv4200023b6laj55g1qo%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clplmmv4200033b6l6lgous1n%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clplmmv4200053b6lgwzxp2wp%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clplmmv4200023b6laj55g1qo%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clplmmv4200023b6laj55g1qo%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpsjuc0800023b6lhk5akr61%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A19%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A22%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A19%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A22%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fredux%252Fstore.ts%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpsjvt1400023b6lbjkw2gy2%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A20%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A2%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A20%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A2%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FButton.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpsjvt1400023b6lbjkw2gy2%2522%257D%252C%2522clplmmv4200053b6lgwzxp2wp%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clplmmv4200053b6lgwzxp2wp%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clplmmv4200043b6lj60zho24%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clplmmv4200043b6lj60zho24%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522SANDBOX_INFO%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clplou7ca02cl3b6lxkjqvlee%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clplmmv4200033b6l6lgous1n%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clplmmv4200033b6l6lgous1n%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: `dispatch` isn't an "async" operation. The issue here is a stale closure over the selected `buttonValue` state in a stale closure over the `onSubmit` callback function that is passed as a prop to `Button`. The dispatched `setButtonValue ` action has to be processed by the reducers and trigger a `Parent` component rerender before the new value is closed over in scope. This all happens ***after*** `onSubmit` is called and the `onButtonClick` callback function returns. This is the "why is happening" answer. I don't know what you are trying to accomplish here though.

Comment: If `setButtonValue` was an asynchronous action you could `await` its return/completion *then* call `onSubmit` with the current `buttonValue` value. Without seeing a more concrete [mcve] it's difficult to say what actual issue or problem you might be trying to solve for here. Perhaps you can [edit] and clarify the use case you need.

Comment: The link to the playground produces a minimal example: when clicking the button, I want it to display `here with value 'inside button'` rather than `here with value 'initial value`. You're correct in that this is due to a stale closure--I'm particularly wondering what are best practices here. Is it generally to lean more heavily on asynchronous actions?

Comment: Is there some other playground you are referring to? The sandbox you included in your post uses completely different code that that in your post. Like I said though, without a more accurate/complete [mcve] for what you are actually trying to accomplish we can't really make good specific suggestions.

Comment: Yep seems that the codesandbox link was bad, I've updated it. Please let me know if you're able to see the correct playground now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that `onSubmit` has a stale closure over the selected `buttonValue` from ***before*** the button is clicked and dispatches the `setButtonValue` action to update that state.

Since there's no asynchronous logic involved here I wouldn't recommend updating the redux code to make `setButtonValue` an asynchronous action. Props drilling is obviously an issue on its own as well.

My suggestion here would be to simply import the `store` and access the current state in the `onSubmit` callback.

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "./Button"
import { useSelector} from "react-redux";
import store from "../redux";
import { getButtonValue } from "../redux/store";
 
export const Parent = () => {
  const buttonValue = useSelector(getButtonValue);

  const onSubmit = () => {
    const insideButtonValue = getButtonValue(store.getState());
    console.log(`Closed over outside button value '${buttonValue}'`);
    console.log(`Inside button value '${insideButtonValue}'`);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <span>Hello world!</span>
      <Button onSubmit={onSubmit} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit using-useselector-value-in-function-property]